# React - old var syntax vs. class extends

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to convert some of my older syntax into the new ES6 syntax. I have a button that that toggles favorited / unfavorited classes and it works in the old syntax and I'm wondering what I'm missing in my conversion.

**This old version works fine:**

import React from 'react';

```
var BtnFav = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {favorited: false};
  },
  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({favorited: !this.state.favorited});

  },
  render() {
    var favStatus = this.state.favorited ? 'btn btn-fav' : 'btn btn-notfav';
    return (
      <button className={favStatus} onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = BtnFav;
```

**While this does not:**

```
import React from 'react';

class BtnFav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {favorited: false};
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({favorited: !this.state.favorited});

  }
  render() {
    var favStatus = this.state.favorited ? 'btn btn-fav' : 'btn btn-notfav';
    return (
      <button className={favStatus} onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
    );
  }
};

module.exports = BtnFav;
```

Comment: If you are using ES6 modules your last line should be `export default BtnFav`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand in ES6, component classes do not autobind `this` to non React methods. In your constructor, add:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you. I put that in the constructor and it works fine.